# Calling an event of other class through a thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

The situation is as follows:

I have a class which creates a main Form. It keeps the created object of the main Form as a static member like this:

```
public static mainAppWnd;
```

and the Form is created somewhere in the `main` code like this:

```
mainAppWnd = new MainAppWnd();
```

Now, I have to keep only one instance of this application opened at a time and I am doing that through Mutex. That part works fine. When a second instance of that app is opened, I have to check that whether it contains some command line arguments or not. If it does, I have to pass those command line args to the existing running instance and inside that running instance, I have to open a new form. The opening of this new form will be handled inside `MainAppWnd` class. To do this stuff, I have used pipes and used `Listen` in  a thread. My thread function is like this:

```
public static void Listen()
{
    NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("49A252BB-C0FC-4bdb-8CA7-522A3BAE3432");
    server.WaitForConnection();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];
    int bytesread = server.Read(buffer, 0, 1000);

    string args = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesread - 1);
    args.Trim();
    string[] arrArgs = args.Split(' ');
    mainAppWnd.LaunchNewForm(arrArgs.ToList()); //This line crashes because of a UI Call across threads.
}
```

In the above code, last line crashes because of a UI Call across threads. Now, I understand that I have to somehow pass a message to the MainAppWnd asynchronously, so that this new form gets launched in it's own pre-existing context but I have not been able to do so. Had it been C++, I would have simply done a `::PostMessage()` and it would have worked but what would be the simplest way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is Windows Forms, and that `mainAppWnd` is a `Form` or something similar, you can use:

```
Action action = () => mainAppWnd.LaunchNewForm(arrArgs.ToList());
mainAppWnd.BeginInvoke(action);
```

[`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) and [`Control.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) are used to execute a delegate on the UI thread associated with the control that you call them on. The difference between the two is that `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous (fire and forget) whereas `Invoke` blocks until the delegate has been executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Invoke and BeginInvoke is clear to me. Can you explain the magic behind `() => mainAppWnd.LaunchNewForm(arrArgs.ToList());' a little bit?

Comment: @Aamir: That's just a lambda expression - an easy way of creating a delegate without writing a whole separate method.

Comment: Thanks. I'm back to your book then :)